# Pronunciation of "Ainpöckisch Bier"

Tags: pronunciation, history, bavarian

While doing research on German beer, I came across the story that beer from Einbeck, *Einbecksch or Einbeckisch Bier*, came to be pronounced *Ainpöckisch Bier* in Bavaria in the 16th century, and this later changed into *ein Bockbier*.

But how plausible is this story? I find it very odd, linguistically speaking, that a "B" sound would change into a "P" sound and then back into a "B" sound later. Things like that are not common at all.
Also, I don't know what the difference would be in pronunciation between "ein" and "ain".
So am I missing something about the original pronunciation? What did it actually sound like when they said it? I've tried to find lists of historical pronunciations of words, but I haven't found any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite plausible.

First of all, *ain* is the more logical pronounciation since *ein* is the same, but shouldn't be. *Ein* if read as strictly a contracted diphtong should be pronounced *e* + *i* ➔ IPA: [ɛɪ̯], but it is:

> [AUSSPRACHE](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_)
>   Betonung: ein- 
>   **Lautschrift: [aɪ̯n]**

The name of the town has undergone quite a few changes over time, some not easy to follow:

> [Einbeck](https://web.archive.org/web/20161203022113/https://www.ndr.de/ndr1niedersachsen/programm/ortsnamenforscher109.html)
>
> Alte Bezeichnungen: 1103-1106 Enbiche, 1105 Enbike, 1134 Eguuardo preposito de Enbeka, 1139 Einbeche, 1146–1154 prepositus de Embeke
>
> Das Grundwort  ist "-beke". Es ist also von einem Flussnamen auszugehen. Das Bestimmungswort ist zunächst als "En-" überliefert. Es ist wohl von einer alten Wurzel "ei-", "oi-", "i-", also "gehen" auszugehen, die mit verschiedenen Erweiterungen, wie etwa "ire", also "gehen", "eva-", "īlian", also "eilen", und mit "n"-Ableitung in den Flussnamen "I(h)na", Nebenfluss der Oder, "Eine", Nebenfluss der Wipper, "Einupis" in Litauen, "Ain", Nebenfluss der Rhône, vorliegt. An diese Bewegungswurzel kann Einbeck gut angeschlossen werden.

The local dialect still writes it [*Aimbeck*](https://nds.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aimbeck) (between ɑ e m b ɛ g & ɛ: m b ɛ k   with a long *e*)

The brew then was subject to transformation as well

> [Bockbier](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bockbier) n. ein Starkbier, dessen Bezeichnung von der niedersächsischen Stadt *Einbeck*, früher *Eimbeck*, herzuleiten ist und zunächst *Eimbeckisch*, *Einbeckisch* Bier (16. Jh.) genannt wird. Die Stadt erlangt bereits im Spätmittelalter Berühmtheit durch Herstellung und Ausfuhr eines anerkannten Hopfenbieres, das seit Anfang des 17. Jhs. auch in Bayern gebraut und mit Vokalwechsel e zu o in der zweiten Silbe *ampokhisch pier* (München 1630), *Aimbock, Oambock* genannt wird. Im 19. Jh. kommt die Kurzform *Bock* m. auf, die als *un bock* ‘ein Glas Bier’ ins Frz. entlehnt wird. Die Darstellung der Ziegenböcke bzw. Ziegenbockköpfe auf Verkaufsanzeigen, Etiketts beruht auf späterer volkstümlicher Umdeutung, indem der Name des Bieres mit dem betreffenden Tier in Zusammenhang gebracht wird. Bockwurst f. Die Wurst aus einem Gemisch von magerem Fleisch hat ihre Bezeichnung von der ursprünglich zur Bockbierzeit verzehrten Wurstart (19. Jh.).

The change then from *p* to *b* and back is not really 'odd', but a common occurence in [*Lautverschiebung:*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweite_Lautverschiebung)

> G: /*b​ʰ​/→/*b/
>   V: /*p/→/*b/    3   /*b/→/p/    dt. Berg, bist → zimbr. Perg, pist  8.–9.   teilweise Bairisch und Alemannisch
>
> Die Phase 3 hat einen geografisch begrenzteren Radius als die Phase 2. Hier wurden die stimmhaften zu stimmlosen Verschlusslauten.
>   b → p

Added to this is the phenomenon that in some regions *[Grimminalbollizey](http://witze.net/fahrzeugkontrollen-witze)* is how people pronounce *Kriminalpolizei* – now – and that for the timeframe to analyse there was no standardised orthography and regional or dialectal variations much stronger than today.

This last fact makes "What did it actually sound like when they said it?" very difficult to answer. We would need a more focussed time, region and origin of the speaker to approach this.

A suggestion for a native from Einbeck promoting the style of *Bier* at around 1700 would probably be something like aɪ n b ə k ɪ ʃ   (with a longish *e*) or aɪ n b ɛ k ɪ ʃ (with a shorter *e* before the written *ck* ).

Comment: Regarding p/b, I am not sure how much difference there is between them in Bavarian anyway.